# BigQuery, Python insert to bigquery in batches for streaming service ('tell' error)

Tags: python, json, google-bigquery

I am calling an API and it returns roughly 100,000 rows of JSON objects. I am trying to load using Load config but get an error. I am loading a list with dictionatires and then using json.dumps to convert Python object to JSON object. I am also appending to an exiting table in BigQuery.

The error: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'tell' (happens at job = bigquery_client.load_table_from_file)

I do see that there is the option to load a csv or json file but I'd rather go through loading a json object directly if possible.

```
def export_items_to_bigquery(self):

        job_config = bq.LoadJobConfig()
        job_config.autodetect = True
        job_config.source_format = 'NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON'
        json_delimit = '\n'.join([json.dumps(item) for item in JSONDict])
        table_id = '{}.{}.{}'.format(self.project_id, self.dataset_id, self.table)
        table = bigquery_client.get_table(table_id)
        job = bigquery_client.load_table_from_file(
        json_delimit, table, job_config=job_config)

        job.result()
        print("Loaded {} rows into {}:{}.".format(job.output_rows, self.dataset_id, self.table))
```

Using print statement testing of the json_delimit variable above, below is the JSON newline structure. It looks fine so not sure why I get the error.

```
{"icao_address": "A69D03", "timestamp": "2020-03-11T17:27:36Z", "latitude": 32.878402, "longitude": -95.075067, "altitude_baro": 26000, "heading": 230.0, "ground_speed": 350.0, "vertical_rate": 0, "on_ground": false, "callsign": "JTL525", "tail_number": "N525RL", "collection_type": "terrestrial", "origin_airport_iata": "TXK", "destination_airport_iata": "ACT"}
{"icao_address": "A56643", "timestamp": "2020-03-11T17:27:36Z", "latitude": 33.391205, "longitude": -86.070355, "altitude_baro": 26700, "heading": 250.0, "ground_speed": 380.0, "vertical_rate": 890, "squawk_code": "5750", "on_ground": false, "callsign": "SKW3917", "tail_number": "N447SW", "collection_type": "terrestrial", "flight_number": "OO3917", "origin_airport_iata": "ATL", "destination_airport_iata": "MLU"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Relevant lines from the code pasted:

```
        json_delimit = '\n'.join([json.dumps(item) for item in JSONDict])


        job = bigquery_client.load_table_from_file(
           json_delimit, table, job_config=job_config)
```

Note that the method `load_table_from_file` expects a `file`, not a `string`. Please provide a file instead of a string.